# Fluent configuration for base entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have the following BaseEntity

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string CreateUserId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string ModifyUserId { get; set; }
}
```

All my other entities derive from it. Now I'd like to use fluent configuration instead of the DataAnnotations. Do I really have to configure the MaxLength of the two string properties in every single `DbModelBuilder` configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I really have to configure the MaxLength of the two string
>   properties in every single DbModelBuilder configuration?

No. You can configure base type validations and EF will apply them on derived types. For example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().Property(x => x.CreateUserId).HasMaxLength(36);
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().Property(x => x.ModifyUserId).HasMaxLength(36);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**Update (as per your comment):**

You can use the (rather new) `Properties()` method to define mapping and validations based on property names rather than on entity types.

For example:

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "CreateUserId").Configure(x => x.HasMaxLength(36));
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "ModifyUserId").Configure(x => x.HasMaxLength(36));
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but I want to get rid of the DataAnnotation

Comment: Now I get an Exception that `BaseEntity` has no key defined.

Comment: @Sandro, See my revision. I added `Ignore<BaseEntity>()`. Assuming you *do* have keys defined for your derived types, it should work just fine.

Comment: Now I'm back to varchar(max) for these fields because `BaseEntity` is ignored on model creation

Comment: Can't you move the key declaration (`public int Id { get; set; }`) to the `BaseEntity` as well?

Comment: No, all Id's must have the table name as a prefix. So the entity is the only place for this declaration.

Comment: Great! It worked. I would have preferred not to use "magic" strings, but I think I can live with it.

Comment: If you'll go C# 6, you'll be able to avoid the "magic strings" using the `nameof` operator.